# Checking if a property exists in "window" fails if "window." is not prepended

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a property exists in window, so I did this:

This code works:

```
if (window.foo) {
    alert("exists");
}
else {
    alert("doesn't exist");
}
```

**Output**:

doesn't exist

I thought the next code should work too because as far as I know when you define variables and you are not inside a function they are created as a property of the "window" object so this should be equivalent:

```
if (foo) { //it fails here "foo is not defined"
    alert("exists");
} else {
    alert("doesn't exist");
}
```

To my surprise it didn't work. My question is why it doesn't work if I don't prepend window?

Comment: Where did you see that variables not defined in a function are automatically added to the window object?

Comment: `if (typeof foo !== 'undefined')`

Comment: @Mike var myName = "Alfredo Osorio"; alert(window.myName); //Alfredo Osorio

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum nice that should be the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of the `Window` object as a "giant closure", which encapsulates all the others. Now think about this:

```
var ext = "test";
function myScope() {
    var ext = "foo"; //new variable in myScope's scope
    console.log(ext); //foo
}
function changeExt() {
    ext = "bar";//ext is not defined in this scope, so JS will look in the chain of scopes and set the value to the defined var in the global scope
    console.log(ext);
}
myScope();
console.log(ext); //test
changeExt();
console.log(ext); //ext has been changed by changeExt to bar
```

Why is this happening? Because by using `window.property` you're trying to access an undefined property of the `window` object, not referencing to an **undeclared** var.

If you try to do the same thing without using the `var` keyword in the global closure you will get the same result, because it is the last of the scopes chain.

Now let's think about it like a giant object:

```
var myObj = {prop: 'defined'};
```

Assuming that `myObj` is the "global object", if you try to access `prop` JS will redirect you to `myObj.prop`(or it will try to do this), if the property (named for example) `foo` isn't declared you will get your `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 7):

The first version is [property access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), it can't find the property so it returns undefined. The second is trying to access undefined variable .

Use what elclanrs suggested:

```
if(typeof foo !== "undefined"){
    alert("exists");
} else {
    alert("doesn't exist");
}
```

### Why?

This is because of the [`GetValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) specified in the language specification.

> .3. If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a ReferenceError exception.

This is what happens in the `if(foo)` case, since `foo` was not defined before.

On the other hand, if its an object the following happens:

> 1. Let base be the result of calling GetBase(V).
> 2. Let O be ToObject(base).
> 3. Let desc be the result of calling the [[GetProperty]] internal method of O with property name P.
> 4. If desc is undefined, return undefined.

So `window.foo` returns the primitive language value `undefined` which is falsy.

Comment: +1 — the OP is confused between property access and identifier resolution.